# About Ambient Light sensor in iphone

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.

I got the information about the iphone sensors from http://ipod.about.com/od/ipodiphonehardwareterms/qt/iphone-sensors.htm. But I didn't get information about how to use ambient sensor in iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, and the framework is public.

You can activate the connection to the sensor like so :

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];
```

BTW, it doesn't seem to be using the light sensor, because proximity sensing would tweak out in a dark room.

However, the API call basically blanks the screen when you hold the phone up to your face. Not useful for interaction, sadly.

Here is a guide about iPhone sensors :
[iPhone sensors](http://learningiphoneprogramming.com/pdf/The_Sensors_in_your_iPhone.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Ya i have seen the guide. But i want to find out how much light is available in the area surrounding the iPhone for that from the information given from http://ipod.about.com/od/ipodiphonehardwareterms/qt/iphone-sensors.htm this link ambient sensor will do exactly same.But there is no information available for how to use it.

Comment: I grant you, the light sensor is not the most spoken off feature to play with, and to be frank, I have a feeling that pre-iphone4 sensors will not give you very "detailed" results. But thats why i have +1'ed your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this answer actually address the question of accessing the "ambient light sensor".  The ambient sensor is used for a host of things beyond proximity to the face, for example, in auto-adjusting brightness.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a [link](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AppleISL29003) to a description of the ambient light sensor hardware with example code that shows how to access it.

Comment: +1 for a great link, but you'd improve your answer by giving more information about what you're linking to. You might say something like: "Here's a link to a description of the ambient light sensor hardware with example code that shows how to access it."

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.