# how does the iphone app Cardiographdetect heartbeat?

Tags: iphone

Here is some info of the cardiograph app if you dont know it:
  http://www.spotlightofpeace.com/techarea/photos/cardiograph-application-to-measure-heartbeat-from-iphone-and-ipad-camera/

Looks like it is senses the light. I know here is some discussion of ambient light sensor:   [About Ambient Light sensor in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408840/about-ambient-light-sensor-in-iphone)

but not sure if this app uses this sensor, does anyone know better about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the camera and not the ambient light sensor. You place your finger over the camera and it then measures the amount of light entering (after passing through your finger) and looks for regular changes (caused by the changing oxygen level of the blood)